# How xTaskCreate function not follow the C procedural method?

Tags: c, freertos

The freertos code is written in C language. And C language is procedural language it means if A function call the B function and B function call the C function,the program will complete the C function first, then return to B, it complete B function second then return to A and then it complete the A function work.
And if in any case function C as infinite loop in it then, C function never return to A.

Question is,
If A functin create the `xTaskCreate` task and pass the infinite loop function, then `xTaskCreate` function keep running the infinite loop function and also we can do other stuff in A function after `xTaskCreate`.

But question is `xTaskCreate` is nothing but C function which takes some parameters,when we pass the function with infinite loop, why it is not stuck in that infinte loop?

Should I explain more, my question?

Comment: `xTaskCreate` creates a new task that executes independently and concurrently from the calling task.  You may want to review the concept of tasks.

Comment: Hello mevets, I checked the freertos documentation but there they explain about working of functions. Also, review the task.c file where xTaskCreate in declare, yeah there they calling the another function, but as I said after completion of that function program should return right, but it is not working that way. I want to know how independently and concurrently this task works.  Do you have any link which explain this? And if want to make function how should I? any example? ------ thanks for the quick response

Comment: If you want to go down this road, there is a lot to understand; but from the basics:   If I have a pointer to a processors register set, and can make the processors execute with those values in its registers, I can make it execute at any address, with any stack, and any other register values that are interesting to the instructions that its program counter (/instruction pointer) register are about to execute.  Freertos' create task creates a stack & set of registers that permits the destination to execute forever.

Comment: Hello mevets, thanks for explaining, can you  refer any book or any other documents where I learn all this things or any youtube videos or github repo where tuturial are available?

Comment: Text books on operating system design and implementation talk about this.  The problem is, how far do you want to go?   Some books, xinu (https://xinu.cs.purdue.edu/) provide a good foundation about operating system concepts and implementation details; whereas ones specific to Unix or Linux are overwhelmingly detailed about implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

`xTaskCreate` does not run the task function. Instead, it adds the task function into some kind of list which keeps the function pointers of the tasks. The task function is run when the RTOS kernel (*scheduler*) decides to run that function.

The RTOS is able to *preempt* any task, because it uses hardware interrupts, which can happen any time unless they are disabled. Interrupts don't need to wait for a function return, as their name suggests. There should be at least one interrupt associated with the RTOS, which runs the *scheduler* when fired.

RTOS is able to switch execution context, because it has access to hardware program counter and stack pointer registers. Of course, it saves the current state of the current task in a some memory structure before switching, so that it can continue the execution of that task later.

This answer is a informal and somewhat incomplete summary of RTOS concepts. OP needs to get familiar with the general operating system & multitasking concepts.

Comment: Thanks Tagli. I think I need to learn lots of thinks to understand Freertos overall concepts. Can any guys give me the reference so I can  learn all this things?

Comment: @RaghavJha , have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEq3-p0GWGI